# What happens when you change space of test functions associated with weak derivatives?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Recall that $u \in L^2(0,T;H^1)$ has weak derivative $u' \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1})$ iff
$$\int_0^T uv' = -\int_0^T u'v$$
holds for all $v \in C_0^\infty(0,T).$

What happens if we only require that this holds for all $v \in C_0^1(0,T)$? What changes? What issues are there to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the definition of a distribution involves infinitely differentiable functions is to make it possible to define derivatives of all orders of any distribution. However, if you stick to distributions of orders at most  $1$ (which is usual in the context of 2nd order elliptic problems), then the space of test functions can be taken to be $C^1$, as gerw explained. Unless you want to differentiate the elements of $H^{-1}$ once more, which is unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing changes at all.

Define $W(0,T) = L^2(0,T; H^1) \cap H^1(0,T; H^{-1})$.
Note that for $u \in W(0,T)$ the mapping
$$
v \mapsto \int_0^T u \, v' + u' \, v \, \mathrm{d}t
$$
is continuous from $H_0^1(0,T)$ to $H^{-1}$. Hence, if the mapping is zero on the dense subspace $C_0^\infty(0,T)$, it is zero on the whole space $H_0^1(0,T)$, in particular on the subspace $C^1_0(0,T)$.

Comment: Thanks. So you have shown that the weak derivative condition with $C_c^\infty$ implies the weak derivative condition with $C_c^1$. OK. But presumably the converse doesn't hold, so these statements aren't equivalent. So then couldn't we be in the case where we have some parabolic PDE, and we get different solutions depending on the test space we use to define the weak derivative?